# Rendering single label for multiple parts

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a map of Canada and the United States that's broken down by electoral districts. At near zoom levels, I have labels for the electoral districts. Closer zoom reveals more information (the names of MPs or Reps and party controlling that district).

For that, label scale functionality works great and the functionality is good enough to keep from getting too cluttered.

[image: Electoral districts]

[image: Electoral districts with fine detail]

However, if I want to label higher levels, the issue is that, of course, all those labels get repeated every electoral district. So Michigan and Ontario will have that label on *every* district, and similarly further zoomed out will do so for America and Canada.

[image: State or province labels over electoral district]

I know about the dissolve function, but that's not much use as I need to keep the subdivisions.

Essentially, I'm looking for any solution that is the *opposite* of "Label every feature of a multipart feature" -- i.e. to label only one of multiple parts that have a common attribute, like `MI` or `ON`.

Answer (score 12):

You can use the following expression in "Layer Styling > Label > Placement > Geometry Generator".

```
collect( $geometry, group_by:="common_attribute")
```

[image]

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Answer (score 11):

You can use an expression in the Geometetry Generator of the label postion tab.

[image]

This expression uses subdivision centroids at scale < 100000, for scales greater, it uses the centroid of subdivisions grouped by an attribute.

```sql
CASE
    WHEN
        @map_scale < 100000
    THEN
        $geometry
    ELSE        
        centroid(
            collect(
                expression:= $geometry,
                group_by:=state
            )
        )
END
```

[image]

##### Notes:

You may need an additional `CASE` statement in the label value expression to display different information.

The centroid of the collected geometries may fall outside the boundary of an individual polygon. In which case you can try `point_on_surface` in place of `centroid`.

Answer (score 9):

To label only the **largest feature** of the same category (same electoral district, here based on the field named `"NAME"`), use `Label Placement > Geometry Generator` with this expression:

```
coalesce(
    order_parts(
        collect($geometry, "NAME"), 
        area($geometry),
        False
        )
    )
```

*Before: mainland + all islands labeled:*
[image]

*After: only mainland is labelled:*
[image]