# Automatically making labels go in certain location of Legal Land Locations in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling

I am working on a project in AB, Canada, and I am trying to find a good way to show quarter sections on my map. Each quarter section (as the name implies) has four sections. Is there anyway I can make it that the 23 is in the centre of the quarter section?

This is what I have on my map:

[image]

And I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Do the answers to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/424303/128665) help?

Comment: add a "section` layer ?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate point layer and label the points:

1. Dissolve the 1/4-sections using their number as the 'dissolve field' (this will group them all together into polygon sections with a single value eg: '23')
2. Create centroids for the polygons
3. Label the centroids (no labels for the 1/4-sections layer)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that there is a field that uniquely identifies the 4 quarters of each quarter section (i.e. NW,NE,SE,SW) use rule-based labeling to only label one of these. Then let the geometry generator do the work on placement.

If you choose to label only the northwest quadrants then in placement under the label section of layer properties, set mode to "Offset from Centroid", check the box for geometry generator and enter:

make_point(x_max($geometry),y_min($geometry))

Choose the option Polygon/MultiPolygon below that.