# Advice on mapping tool (world map, Robinson projection, visualise wine production)

Tags: qgis, software-recommendations, mapping, tableau

I’m looking for some advice on finding the right mapmaking tool. I think what I want is rather simple but I’ve gotten stuck every turn I took.

**Requirements:**
I’d like a map of the world in Robinson projection, showing only countries. No further layout or design requirements.
Be able to visualise wine production per country, using circles.
Be able to edit the map afterwards in Illustrator (export to pdf, svg).

**Tried so far:**
I’ve tried QGIS. It got me pretty far, but I got stuck on the tool visualising wine production for not just each country, but also repeating each circle for each island belonging to each country. I have not been able to find a solution for that issue.
I tried Tableau. Much easier than QGIS, but in order to get a Robinson projection I needed to apply hacks, and they didn't work. On top of that the pdf export has the map of the world as an image, not vector.

Any advice for an easy to use, free tool to get the above?

UPDATE:
Here's the end result I created using Flourish and after that editing in Illustrator, to give an idea of what I was looking for.
[image]

Comment: I would think QGIS would be fine. For visualizing the wine data, would using a [heatmap](https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/creating_heatmaps.html) solve your problems?

Comment: Having multiple points per country is happening in QGIS most likely because your data contains multipolygons for countries. Can you share more details what data are you using to represent the countries (I am guessing Natural Earth?) and how are you doing that point visualization now?

edit: one idea that you could do, is to pre-process your data with "Point on surface", which creates you one point for each feature and then scale these features.

Comment: @Binx: It might work, but I would really like to go for circles. By the way, in a last attempt I tried Flourish and that worked rather easily. So in the end I did get it to work. But thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: @tjukanov: I am using Natural earth (ne_10m_admin_0_countries). For the circles: In the Layer Styling panel I select the "Single Symbol" renderer from the drop-down menu. Then I click the "Symbol" button and select "Simple Marker." I set the shape to "circle". I'll look into the Point on surface preprocessing for other maps if I'm going to use QGIS again. Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: @R.Boomgaard could you provide an illustration of what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: QGIS will do the job for you. See here how to solve the problem of creating just one symbology per country, without reapeating for each island: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/424349/88814

Comment: @Binx: I've udated the question with the image I created to show what I was looking for.

Comment: You might want to add an answer how you finally achieved your goal.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to visualize this data on a world map using Flourish. Flourish directly mapped one data point to a country instead of also to islands, and that was what I was looking for. So to answer the question I posted, for a rather simple use case such as above, Flourish will do fine.